# How to hide 'require' function from a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack, jquery-plugins

I am using [twism jQuery plugin](https://github.com/cody1213/twism), which makes use of 'require' function internally. This conflicts with webpack, which defines its own 'require', which results in the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).toUrl is not a function
```

The offending code is this line:

```
 b = require.toUrl("twism").replace("jquery.twism", "maps/" + u);
```

How is it possible to isolate the global webpack function from this code, without modifying it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add webpack specific handler prior to that line:

```
if (typeof(__webpack_require__) === 'function') {
   // hack for webpack - ask it to copy the map being used to the build location
   const buildUrl = require('./maps/' + file);       
   url = buildUrl.default;
   // the following line is for debug and demonstration purpose
   console.log('Moved file to url: ', file, url);
}
```

and replace the original if with else if clause:

Original:

```
//hack for RequireJS/Bower
if (typeof(require) !== 'undefined' && settings.map != "custom") {
     b = require.toUrl("twism").replace("jquery.twism", "maps/" + u);
```

Replace with:

```
else if (typeof(require) !== 'undefined' && settings.map != "custom") {
    //hack for RequireJS/Bower
    b = require.toUrl("twism").replace("jquery.twism", "maps/" + u);
```

I posted this as a pull request to the twism author's Github.

Answer (score -1):

Can you fully qualify the require call?
e.g.

```
 b = twism.require.toUrl("twism").replace("jquery.twism", "maps/" + u);
```

Comment: That does not work. Twism is actually trying to call require, which belongs to another package, in a way that is incompatible with webpack.

Comment: see my answer for details how I solved it.